# Minimal number of generatos in a pushout/Generalization of Grushko's Theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $A_1 \hookleftarrow \mathbb Z \hookrightarrow A_2$ be a diagram of finitely-generated, torsion free groups, where each arrow indicates an injective homomorphism. Let $A$ be the pushout of this diagram.

Can the rank of $A$ be expressed soley in terms of the ranks of the two $A_i$'s here ? In particular, does something intuitive like the following equality hold ?

*$rank(A) \geq rank(A_1) + rank (A_2) - 1$*

I know some examples that show why an immediate generalization of Grushko's Theorem to amalgamated products fails, however, in all these examples, the groups $A_i$ were not torsion free. Any help is highly appreciated